# Images are not loading inside repeater when deploying web application to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I've deployed my asp.net web application following [Microsoft Docs (Deploy to Test)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis).

After deploying my application to IIS there is problem that images inside Repeater control are not loading. While in debugging/development these are loading correctly.

Below is my code (Repeater with Image control):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpBanquetList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        //... other controls
        <asp:Image ID="imgImagePath" ImageUrl='<%#"Images/"+Eval("imgImagePath") %>'
            runat="server" />
        //... other controls
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Windows 7 : IIS 8 : VS15 Community

Comment: Have you checked whether the URL that is being generated in the HTML when you `view source` is the same as the virtual location of the image?

Comment: I've checked that is correct.

Comment: Okay, have you checked whether putting the *same* image URL in the browser loads the image?

Comment: when I entered URL in browser its loading the images.

Comment: If those images (or other files) are not added to the Visual Studio Solutions Explorer, they will not be uploaded when the app is deployed. So you might want to check if the images even exists on the server. And it's always a good idea to use a slash in the front to make sure the root path is uses: `"/Images/"+Eval("imgImagePath")`

Comment: @AsifAli72090 have you checked this https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2009/10/12/funny-problem-windows-7-iis-7-5-images-css-not-showing/

Comment: @Peru Yes, I've checked **"Static Content"** option

Comment: Get `ViewSource` and add the rendered HTML of `<asp:Repeater>` to your question.

Answer (score 4):

It may be posible that you are having issues with relative URLs. You can try somehting like:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpBanquetList" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    //... other controls
    <asp:Image ID="imgImagePath" ImageUrl='<%#"~/Images/"+Eval("imgImagePath") %>'
        runat="server" />
    //... other controls
</ItemTemplate>
```

You may have your images located in `AppRootDirectory\Images\` and you are trying to access them from a page in a different directory than `AppRootDirectory`, lets say `AppRootDirectory\MyWebform\pageWithRepeaterControl.aspx`. In this case the images' relative URLs  will be resolved to something like:

`http://hostName/appName/MyWebForm/Images/` + the value from `Eval("imgImagePath")`. Note that `/Images/` here, is interpreted as a subdirectory of `appName`.

Please take into consideration that `appName` may or may not be part of your project's URL. This depends on how have you deployed your web application, if it  was in the root directory of your website in IIS or as an application in such a website.

You can use the <kbd>~</kbd> operator to get the path relative to the root directory. Using the same examples as before, `~/Images/` would be resolved to `http://hostName/appName/Images/` which would be the `AppRootDirectory\Images\` physical path in your server.

More information about [web project paths here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace asp.net controller with html controller and specify the absolute path in code behind file as follow.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpBanquetList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        //... other controls
         <img id ="imgImagePath" src="<%= AbsolutePath %>images/<%#Eval("imgImagePath")%>"/>
        //... other controls
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

on code behind file

```
 string absolutePath =  this.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + this.Request.Url.Host + ":" + this.Request.Url.Port + this.ResolveUrl("~/");
```